C# language spec for type of a Generic when the type parameter is a struct when using NRT annotations
In this code, the type of new Of<int>().Value is int, not int? even though the field declaration for Value has a ?
Does the C# spec clarify that in this case the type of T? will be a (not-nullable) Value type and not a Nullable Value type? I can't find it.
#nullable enable

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine( new Of<int>().Value.GetType() );
}

class Of<T>
{
    public T? Value;

    public Of(T? value) => Value = value;
    public Of() {}

    public Of<T> Create() => new Of<T>(default);
    
}


The C# spec has not been properly updated for many of the new features. There are separate addendums for these.
Unconstrained type parameters with regards NRT is in the feature spec:

In C#9, ? annotations can be applied to any type parameter, regardless of constraints.
Unless a type parameter is explicitly constrained to value types, annotations can only be applied within a #nullable enable context.
If a type parameter T is substituted with a reference type, then T? represents a nullable instance of that reference type.
var s1 = new string[0].FirstOrDefault();  // string? s1
var s2 = new string?[0].FirstOrDefault(); // string? s2

If T is substituted with a value type, then T? represents an instance of T. (my bold)
var i1 = new int[0].FirstOrDefault();  // int i1
var i2 = new int?[0].FirstOrDefault(); // int? i2

If T is substituted with an annotated type U?, then T? represents the annotated type U? rather than U??.
var u1 = new U[0].FirstOrDefault();  // U? u1
var u2 = new U?[0].FirstOrDefault(); // U? u2

If T is substituted with a type U, then T? represents U?, even within a #nullable disable context.
#nullable disable
var u3 = new U[0].FirstOrDefault();  // U? u3



Thankyou yes, I think the section of spec you point to clarifies what I was looking for : “If T is substituted with a value type, then T? represents an instance of T.”

Your declaration is too open, because the nullable value type is a lot different than for reference types. If you were to clarify which of the paths you were interested in, the generated code would match your expectations:
class Of<T> where T: struct
{
    T? value; // ie, Nullable<T>
}

